# How do I define an associative array?

Tags: javascript, associative-array, definition

I want to define what I understand is an associative array (or maybe an object) such that I have entries like the following:
    "Bath" = [1,2,5,5,13,21]
    "London" = [4,7,13,25]

I've tried the following:

```
var xref = new Object;
xref = [];
obj3 = {
      offices: []
      };
xref.push(obj3);
```

Then cycling through my data with

```
xref[name].offices.push(number);
```

But I get "TypeError: xref[name] is undefined".  What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is `name` in your example? Also, you should be using an object, not an array. Initializing `xref` with `new Object` and then assigning the value `[]` in the next line is somewhat pointless. I recommend to read [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: `var xref = new Object;
xref = [];` is the same as `var xref = new Object(); xref = new Array();`. You can't use named keys in javascript arrays. Remove the `[]` declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that all I really wanted was a 2 dimensional array with the first dimension being the key (ie. "BATH", "LONDON") and the second being the list of cross-references (ie. 1,2,5,5,13,21) - so I don't need to understand the Object route yet !  The other suggestions may well work and be "purer" but the 2 dimensional array is easier for my old-fashioned brain to work with.

So I did the following:

```
var xref = [];
// go through source arrays
for (i = 0; i < offices.length; i++) { 
  for (j = 0; j < offices[i].rel.length; j++) {
     // Check if town already exists, if not create array, then push index
     if (xref[offices[i].rel[j].town] === undefined) {
        xref[offices[i].rel[j].town] = [];
        alert('undefined so created '+offices[i].rel[j].town);
        };
     xref[offices[i].rel[j].town].push(i);    // Add index to town list
     };
  };
```

I believe from reading other posts that I would have problems if any of the 'offices[i].rel[j].town' were set to undefined but the data doesn't have this possibility.

Now I can access a cross-reference list by doing something like:

```
townlist = "";
for (i = 0; i < xref["BATH"].length; i++) {
   townlist += offices[xref["BATH"][i]].name+' ';
   };
alert(townlist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an object like you do with obj3:

```
var xref = {};
xref.obj3 = obj3;
var name = 'obj3';
xref[name].offices.push(number);
```

Comment: My bad I realised my mistake soon after I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
   arr : [],
}

var name = "vinoth";
obj.arr.push(name);
console.log(obj.arr.length);
console.log(obj.arr[0]);

obj.prop = "Vijay";
console.log(obj.prop);
```

You can use an `object literal`.